# How to download a public folder from sharepoint using wget

Tags: sharepoint, download, wget

I want to download [these public folders](https://hkustconnect-my.sharepoint.com/personal/tfangaa_connect_ust_hk/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?id=%2Fpersonal%2Ftfangaa%5Fconnect%5Fust%5Fhk%2FDocuments%2FDISCOS%2FDISCOS%2DATOMIC&originalPath=aHR0cHM6Ly9oa3VzdGNvbm5lY3QtbXkuc2hhcmVwb2ludC5jb20vOmY6L2cvcGVyc29uYWwvdGZhbmdhYV9jb25uZWN0X3VzdF9oay9FbEhNTXRIc0N3WkxnLUFkUDhaZEpUOEJDQndUT3lBT2lsMVhMdDRFZlBZV1VnP3J0aW1lPWgtc2VrUjhSMlVn) on sharepoint using a command in terminal (`Ubuntu` server connected via `ssh`).

I select all folders then hit Download button, it starts to downloading them in `Firefox`, I tried to copy the download link which is the following and give it to `wget`

```
wget https://japaneast1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/zip?cs=fFNQTw
```

However, it just download few bytes and stops:

```
--2021-05-06 21:41:27--  https://japaneast1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/zip?cs=fFNQTw
Resolving japaneast1-mediap.svc.ms (japaneast1-mediap.svc.ms)... 13.107.136.13
Connecting to japaneast1-mediap.svc.ms (japaneast1-mediap.svc.ms)|13.107.136.13|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 0
Saving to: ‘zip?cs=fFNQTw.5’

zip?cs=fFNQTw.5            [ <=>                         ]       0  --.-KB/s    in `0s`      

2021-05-06 21:41:29 (0.00 B/s) - ‘zip?cs=fFNQTw.5’ saved [0/0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download the file in FireFox since it uses some session and cookie variables. For example, I couldn't download it in Chrome when I wasn't logged in Microsoft account, and when I logged in again I couldn't access the page.

Anyways, the following FireFox add-on was a solution. It copies any required variable and make a link that can be used in curl.

> Download login-protected files from the command line using curl, wget or aria2.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/